# move object upwards but in a random min max value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get my object to move upwards but in a random zig zag direction. i have used the following code to get my object to move upwards.

```
transform.position += transform.up * playerspeed *  Time.deltaTime;
```

However how do i go about making this object move upwards but in a zigzag direction with my own minimum and maximum values. and when it respawns the pathway of the zigzag is random?

Comment: Can you draw an image of the path you're trying to achieve? Are you just trying to add lateral movement to the object, with oscillation between two values? Is every step of the zigzag a random length? should the angle of each segment be the same, or can that vary too? (Again, a visual aid would probably implicitly answer all these.)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is pick an x position and then move to it as you are moving upwards.  Then when you reach it, just repeat the process.

Try this out:

```
private float minBoundaryX = -3f;
private float maxBoundaryX = 3f;
private float targetX;
private float horSpeed = 3f;
private float vertSpeed = 2f;

//Pick a random position within our boundaries
private void RollTargetX()
{
    targetX = Random.Range(minBoundaryX, maxBoundaryX);
}

//Calculate the distance between the object and the x position we picked
private float GetDistanceToTargetX()
{
    return Mathf.Abs(targetX - transform.position.x);
}

private void Update()
{
    //Roll a new target x if the distance between the player and the target is small enough
    if (GetDistanceToTargetX() < 0.1f)
        RollTargetX();
    //Get the direction (-1 or 1, left or right) to the target x position
    float xDirection = Mathf.Sign(targetX - transform.position.x);
    //Calculate the amount to move towards the x position
    float xMovement = xDirection * Mathf.Min(horSpeed * Time.deltaTime, GetDistanceToTargetX());
    transform.position += new Vector3(xMovement, vertSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```